# Updating tableView from another ViewController using segues

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a viewController with a tableView, and another viewController that contains data that I'm trying to pass to the tableView. To add entries to the tableView I used segues, but the problem with segues is that they don't update the tableView permanently. They merely create an instance of the ViewController and add the entry there, but the original object remains unchanged. Both ViewControllers are part of a tab bar controller. What I want is to update the table permanently. Meaning, I want to be able to navigate to the viewController where the table is defined and see that's an entry has been added. Here's the code for the viewController with the tableView:

```swift
import UIKit

class FavoritesViewController: UIViewController {
    
    public var shops = [
        "hello world",
        "hello world",
        "hello world"
    ]
    
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        table.reloadData()
    }
    
}



extension FavoritesViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    
    func add(_ shopName: String) {
        print(shopName)
        shops.append(shopName)
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return shops.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell",for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = shops[indexPath.row]
        return cell
        
    }
    
    // define the action. In this case "delete"
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
        return .delete
    }
    
    // do the actual deleting
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            
            shops.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
        

    }
    
    
}
```

And here's how I'm trying to update (in the case adding an entry) the tableView in the other viewController:

```swift
class MainViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate{

public var shopName:String?

// there are also many other vars, but they're irrelevant

public var favoritesDestinationVC = FavoritesViewController()


// prepares the data for the segue 
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
      
        if segue.identifier == "goToFavs" {
            favoritesDestinationVC = segue.destination as! FavoritesViewController
            if let newShopName = shopName {
                favoritesDestinationVC.shops.append(newShopName)
            }
            
            
        }
    }



}
```

However, when I add the entry the to the table, the segue creates an instance of `FavoritesViewController`, adds that entry there, and then displays it in a popup window like this:
[image]

But when I dismiss this window the changes disappear (the tableView remains the same; 3 times "Hello World").

I want the changes to be saved in the tableView after dismissing this window. Any idea on how to do that? On how to make those changes permanent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your explanation, it looks like. Segue is defined as presenting `FavoritesViewController` modally. and this behavior is expected. By your implementation. Since you are not updating the view controller object which is part of the tab bar controller.

To make the changes in the controller in tab bar controller, Either you access that object using tabcontroller.viewcontrollers. Communicate using another way like a delegate or notification.

Edit:
It totally depends on where you want to access `FavoritesViewController`.

If you want to access from TabBarViewController (based on your view hierarchy it may change. be careful about index and typecasting):

```
let favVC = self.viewControllers?[1] as! FavoritesViewController
favVC.shops.append(newShopName)
```

If you want to access from a view controller which is part of same tab bar controller:

```
var favVC = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as! FavoritesViewController 
favVC.shops.append(newShopName)
```

Note: Viewcontrollers's index depends on viewcontroller order in your tab bar controller. And type casting depends upon your view hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how would I go about doing that in my case? I'm still a beginner and I'm a little confused about this. How would that look like in code?  describing the needed steps is enough. I'll figure out the rest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edited the answer with more detail.